# adding Xml attributes to objects serialized from .NET

Tags: .net, xml, vb.net, serialization

I have a class called CustomerDetails, and I manage these objects in a System.Collections.Generic.List(Of CustomerDetails).  I serialize this object in an ordinary way...

```
    Private Sub CustomerDetailsExportToXml(Details As System.Collections.Generic.List(Of CustomerDetails))
        Dim x As New System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(Details.GetType)
        Using s As New FileStream("customerdetails.xml", FileMode.Create)
        x.Serialize(s, Details)
        End Using
    End Sub
```

...and get ordinary Xml...

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
  <ArrayOfCustomerDetails xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <CustomerDetails>
      <Acronym>MSD</Acronym>
      <FriendlyName>Main Street Diner</FriendlyName>
    </CustomerDetails>
  </ArrayOfCustomerDetails>
```

To aid readability, I want to add an attribute to the CustomerDetails tag called "Acronym" that would contain the value of the  tag:

```
<CustomerDetails Acronym="MSD">
```

I can do this in a post-serialization method where I load/modify/save the Xml, but I'm afraid of the resulting Xml not being de-serializable.  Can the addition of the attribute be done at time of serialization?

Comment: Can you show what your `CustomerDetails` class looks like?  Based on your comment to Marc's answer, I think that would help us understand the problem a little better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you already seem to have `Acronym` with the same value as an *element*, this should be pretty simple to get the serializer to do for you. Presumably right now you have something like:

```
public class CustomerDetails
{
    public string Acronym {get;set;}
}
```

To make that an attribute instead, all you have to do is *ask*:

```
public class CustomerDetails
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Acronym {get;set;}
}
```

You can also do this *without* attributes by configuring the serializer manually, but it is a **lot** more work.

Comment: I figured that there should be some sort of decorator, but I couldn't find the documenetation.

Comment: I'm makring this as the answer, because I didn't ask my question well.  I don't want the attribute -instead- of the child tag.  I want the tag AND the attribute.  My apologies for the poorly-worded question.

Comment: @DWRoelands you could add a second property that simply gets/sets the first, and add the attribute to that: `[XmlAttribute("Acronym")] public string Acronym2NamingIsHard {get => Acronym; set => Acronym = value;}`

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

[Marc Gravell's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75628827/1920035) is much more concise and keeps it so it can be deserialized easily too.

Here is a fiddle using the XmlAttribute decorator: https://dotnetfiddle.net/6T0U4d

**Original Answer**

> I can do this in a post-serialization method where I load/modify/save the Xml, but I'm afraid of the resulting Xml not being de-serializable. Can the addition of the attribute be done at time of serialization?

That is correct. If you mess with the serialization output then it is unlikely that it will be deserializable.

However, what you're asking can be done pretty easily by following these steps:

1. Instead of using a `FileStream` you can use a `StringWriter` to get the output as an in-memory string
2. Take the XML literal and load it into an `XDocument`
3. Loop over the CustomerDetails elements in the ArrayOfCustomerDetails element
4. Set the attribute value to the Acronym element value
5. Remove the Acronym element
6. Save the XDocument XML to your file

For example:

```vb
Dim serializer = New XmlSerializer(details.GetType())
Dim xmlLiteral = String.Empty
Using writer = New StringWriter()
    serializer.Serialize(writer, details)
    xmlLiteral = writer.ToString()
End Using

Dim detailsXmlDocument = XDocument.Parse(xmlLiteral)
For Each customerDetailsElement In detailsXmlDocument.Element("ArrayOfCustomerDetails").Elements("CustomerDetails")
    customerDetailsElement.SetAttributeValue("Acronym", customerDetailsElement.Element("Acronym").Value)
    customerDetailsElement.Element("Acronym").Remove()
Next

IO.File.WriteAllText("customerdetails.xml", detailsXmlDocument.ToString())
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/kAz5Ol

You could get the deserialization to work by just reversing the process.